# find a regular expression to check letter,chinese character and slash(/)

Tags: javascript, regex, expression

i want to check users' input value when he input his name, if his input is a English name, the name only contains letters and must be divided with slash(/), example:
`GeorgeBush, George Bush,GeorgeBush/, dsfsdf/` are wrong; `George/Bush, fdfd/fdfd/sds` are right.
i have find a regular expression like this:`/^[a-zA-Z\u4E00-\u9FA5\/]{1,20}/`. But it can't check `fsfd/` or `/fdsf`. please give me some suggestions. thanks!

Comment: What language/Regex system is this for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not clear exactly what you want, maybe this:

```
^(?=.{1,20}$)[a-zA-Z\u4E00-\u9FA5]+(?:\/[a-zA-Z\u4E00-\u9FA5]+)?$
```

Comment: thank your reply and forgive my poor english, --!. length of user's input must be less than 20, and he can only input english letter(should be divided with '/', in the other words, his input should contains '/') or chinese charactors(no limit). now i have resolve the chinese charactors. but if input are english letters, the regular expression can't work.

Comment: slash can't start of or ends with the input

Comment: @weyoung, why don't you try it first? It will not allow slashes at the  end/beginning of string. For english this seems to cover all you need.

Comment: forgive my ambiguous question, slash divide first name and last name, so it must appear only one time, string like sfsfsdf or GeorgeBush aren't what i want. however, thank your very much.
(string can't contains blank)

Comment: @weyoung, your example shows two slashes as valid? If you wan't just a single optional slash, change the last `*` to `?` (like in the updated answer). If the slash is not optional, remove the last `?` in the answer. Also, on this site, it's common to thank people by up voting (altho you can't do that till you have 15 reputation) and/or accepting answers. (;